# ITurnContext turnContext throws nullreference error after 1 hour of succesfull pro active messaging using NotifyController from MS Proactive example

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using microsoft-bot-framework and the pro active example using the NotifyController. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages.

So far all good, I'm able to send a pro active message to a user:
[image: Postman call + message received in Teams chat]

The issue: **turnContext throws a nullref error**, but only after ~ 1 hour. If the user chats again first to the bot, there is no issue and the turnContext is known.

**The nullref error is thrown at ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync...**

```
namespace ProactiveBot.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/notify")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly string _appId;

        public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
            _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"] ?? string.Empty;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ChatbotResponse response)
        {
            // Set basic reply
            var reply = MessageFactory.Text(response.Text);

            if(response?.Buttons?.Count > 0) // a reply with buttons
            {
                reply = SendSuggestedActions(response.Text,default,response?.Buttons);
            }

            // Target a specific user
            if (response.Recipient_id != string.Empty)
            {
                var recipient = UserCollection.UserSession.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ID == response.Recipient_id).Value;
                await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId,recipient.ConversationReference,(ITurnContext turnContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken) => turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply),default);
```

**Error log**

```
2021-03-31 06:22:07.559 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Connection ID "(xxxxx)", Request ID "(xxxxxx)": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at ProactiveBot.Controllers.NotifyController.Post(ChatbotResponse response) in C:\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\workspace\microsoft-bot-framework\CoreBot\Controllers\NotifyController.cs:line 51at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

------------- Update: alternative approach -------------

```
await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId,recipient.ConversationReference,async (context,token) =>
                    await BotCallback(activity,context,token),default(CancellationToken));
```

were BotCallback is

```
private async Task BotCallback(Activity activity, ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var response = await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity);
        }
```

**throws the same error. Puzzled why turnContext works in the first hour but is null after more then an hour.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found the documentation to be terrible around proactive messaging and it took a lot of trial and error to get right. I'm away from computer right now but if you haven't had an answer by tomorrow I'll post an example of how I achieved it.

Comment: Appreciate that, Nat. Tried an alternative approach, but same error. Updated the question with the other approach and the error as thrown on Azure Log Stream.

Comment: @wvt - We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot).

Comment: I'm indeed trying to combine a "proactive" functionality and "conversation" functionality. Thanks, I'll try this different sample from MS.

Comment: Hi @Nikitha-MSFT, the conversation example always goes through `OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext...`. My issue is pro actively sending messages (eg.: by using a Postman request or via an Azure Function). The turnContext isn't available in that [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so as promised.  Here's how I got proactive messaging to users working...

What you need:

- The user's ID (`userId` in the below example) in Teams. You can get this from a prior interaction or just from querying the users list (`GetConversationPagedMembersAsync`).
- The Team's tenant ID (`tenantId` in the below example).  When a user initially installs our bot, I collect this information and store it in our database.  Note that it can apparently change over time, so I do check it again periodically.

The code:

```
// we only need the user's ID, which we'll get from the DB
var user = new ChannelAccount(userId);

var conversationParams = new ConversationParameters
{
    IsGroup = false,
    Members = new List<ChannelAccount>
    {
        user
    },
    TenantId = tenantId
};

try
{
    var conversation = await _client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParams);
    message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversation.Id);

    var response = await _client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(message);
    return new MessageReference
    {
        ConversationId = conversation.Id,
        MessageId = response.Id
    };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log, or whatever
}
```

Note that it seemed to be important to create the conversation first, and only then call `SendToConversationAsync`, unlike messaging channels where it seems that you could supply the message activity as part of the `ConversationParameters`.

This is how I do all proactive messaging.  I don't use `ITurnContext` at all, except where I'm responding to a user-initiated message, e.g. when they first install the bot to their channel/personal scope.

Comment: I don't (yet) dependency inject the ClientConnecter. Let me try your suggested solution. Thank you so much for your detailed response, Nat!

Comment: *ConnectorClient